# Spring MVC - How can I dynamically switch the implementing class?

Tags: spring, interface, persistence, autowired

My question is about finding the best technique for implementing a bean switcher for managing different sites with different persistent layers.

I designed a server for Customer management and e-eCommerce services.

For each service I am using an API layer, a Controller layer and a persistent layer.

This server is managing multiple sites for different clients.
Up until today, all my sites have used the same persistent layer for all the sites.

Recently, I have a new request for integrating the customers services from an outside server - In other words, Integration with external service.

I am trying to solve this by adding another persistent layer that uses the external service's API, and when I get request from this site, to switch the persistent layer to the outside service (Like a factory).

Lets assume I have details about the site which the request came from....
My goal is to use a kind of 'Factory' for switching between the persistent layers according to the parameters that I pull from the request.

How do I dynamically switch the implementing class of the interface using the Spring MVC tools?

I found this solution: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dynamic-autowire, but I don't think it is the best solution.

Can anyone share a different technique to achieve my goal?

Thank you so much for any help!!!

Asaf

Comment: See https://deinum.biz/2007-01-05-one-application-per-client-database/ for a solution and oldy (before multi-tenant was a thing) but it will work. It works transparently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Factory pattern to solve this issue.

You can define a class that will autowired all types of data services. You should first define an abstraction via interface something like this.

```
interface SomeDao {
 ...
}

@Service(name="someDaoMysql")
class SomeDaoMysqlImpl implements SomeDao {
 ...
}

@Service(name="someDaoApi")
class SomeDaoApiImpl implement SomeDao {
 ...
}
```

Once you have these different variants of the `SomeDao` interface, return one of them based on some parameters.  A factory interface might look like this.

```
enum DaoType{
  API,
  MYSQL;
}


interface SomeDaoFactory { 
 SomeDao getDao( DaoType type);
}



@Component 
class SomeDaoFactoryImpl implements SomeDaoFactory{
  @Aurowired @Qualifier("someDaoMysql") SomeDao someDaoMysql;
  @Aurowired @Qualifier("someDaoApi") SomeDao someDaoApi;
  public SomeDao getDao( DaoType type){
    switch(type){
      case API:
       return someDaoApi;
      case MYSQL:
        return someDaoMysql;
      default:
        throw new IllegalStateExecption("Unknown type"+type);
  }
}
```

Usage

```
@Service
public class SomeFancyServiceImpl implements SomeFancyService{
     @Autowired  SomeDaoFactory someDaoFactory;
    
     @Override
     public void doSomething(){
       SomeDao dao = someDaoFactory.getDao( API );
       // do something with dao
     }
}
```